# don't have permission to acces new pictures on server

Tags: php, joomla, file-permissions, cpanel

i'm working on some new features for a website (with joomla not that i think it's relevant to the probleme) . My problem is i can't access the new pictures i put on the server.
lets say on the images directory i have a.png (old) and b.png (new) , i can see a.png on the browser if i type it's link but b.png will give me :

```
You don't have permission to access /images/face.jpg on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

With cPanel, i checked the permissions (644) and even gave them full permission but nothing. 
what else should i check for ?

Comment: Did you check that file /images/face.jpg exists on server ??

Comment: check your .htaccess on images folder.

Comment: Check .htaccess and the owner of the file. Also check folder permissions. Do any images work in the `/images/` folder ?

Comment: yes all the images on the /images/ folder work except the ones i started puting since yesturday . and yes the file /images/face.jpg exists

Comment: try `echo get_current_user();` then make sure that user owns the folder and files.

Comment: how do i make sur that user owns the files ?

Comment: File and folder ownership can only be changed by the user on very little hosts. The majority of the time, the host has to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It was a joomla related problem after all , since the site is under the 1.5 version i should have put the images in the stories folder too. starting from version 1.6 this folder doesn't existe anymore. So i put the images their and it's fixed.